# How to only allow authenticated (logged in) users to access Spring restful service

Tags: angularjs, spring, authentication, spring-security, single-page-application

The architecture of the web project is as follows:

1. There is a **Spring MVC restful web service** running to serve HTTP restful APIs.
2. A **node.js express service** is running to serve web pages with **AngularJS**. It also offers some HTTP resful service for the AngularJS to call, which bascially calls the Spring Restful API and returns the result to the front end AngularJS.

The call flow is:

1. The AngularJS on the page initiates API calls to the express restful service.
2. Then the express service calls the Spring MVC restful service to get the needed results.
3. The express service returns the result to the front end AngularJS. Before getting back to Angular, it can post-process the data in order to fit the need of front end.

---

How can I only allow the users who logged in at the front end (also by calling the login restful API) to make subsequent calls to other services offered by the Spring MVC restful service?

The tricky thing is that the front end (AngularJS + Express which serves the page and also proxies the service call to Spring Restful) and the back end (Spring Restful service) are separated parts. So I am not sure if Spring Security can do the job. Or can I use some other way? Your thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as a user logs in to the system, you can add his session id in some cache(application level variables) in Spring side. Now send this session id back to the user after he has logged in. The user at the client side should store this session id in his webstorage (sessionstorage or localstorage). Now for each rest service call, pass the session id along with the data to the server.

Spring side when receiving the request should first check for the sessionId, validate the session id with the ones stored in the cache.

This way you can make sure only logged in users are accessing the rest service.

Comment: Thanks, @Upesh M. The login service is basically a restful API called with the username and password. So how can I generate the "session ID" as you mentioned?

Comment: normally servlet container opens an httpSession when your first request comes, in java, you can use request.getSession().getId() for getting the sessionId.

Comment: @blue123 Or else, since servlet container maintains a session for all the requests coming from the same user, when you authenticate the user, add a userVO to his sessionObject. Now in the subsequent requests check if a valid userVO is present in his session.

Comment: thanks again. I think it is more of API to API interaction between Node.js and Spring. The user interaction stops at the node.js service layer. So maybe the spring service cannot handle the session like your mentioned since the call is from the node.js service, not the user?

Comment: @blue123 So you mean to say that session will be same for all users? Then you have to generate a random hash value for different users instead of sessionId

Comment: the API calls between Express and Spring RESTful APIs are stateless currently. In this case, are all the users sharing the same session?